# Reserve a code for the new record

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table in SQL Server and I use Entity Framework to work with SQL Server database. I want reserve a code for new record (new entity of the table) when user click a button to add a new record into table before saving the record, so when another user click a button to add new record new Code (lastcode+1) reserved for it before save the record.

How can I implement this in C# and Entity Framework? Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by a code?  Are you saying you want to store what the PK value of the record would be before you insert it?

Comment: @Jim No. the code is another field in my table

Comment: If you're using SQL Server **2012**, you can look at using a [`SEQUENCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) to achieve this. Otherwise you'll have to wait until the row **IS** inserted and use an `INT IDENTITY` column that automatically gets a value when the insert happens

Comment: @marc_s I Use Sql Server 2008 R2. i want reserve a code before saving the record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jean-Bernard Pellerin's answer would definitely work. But the thing I don't like about that  approach is that all the columns besides the ID must be nullable, or have defaults set that may not make sense for the entity. Because of this, I try to avoid the requirement to reserve a code or ID for the entity before it is created.

But sometimes you can't avoid it. In that case, I split the entity into two different entities -- one for the actual entity, and another to track the process of creating it. For example, if your record is the `Record` entity, you would also have a `RecordCreation` entity. `RecordCreation` has a property for your reserved code value, and it also has a nullable DateTime property named `DateComplete`. When you go to create a new entity, you actually create the `RecordCreation` entity, and set its code value -- this reserves its code. Then later, when you are ready to create the actual entity, you also update the `DateComplete` column. This has several advantages:

1. You don't have partially complete entities that never finished being created litering your database.
2. You have a record of attempts to create an entity that never finished, and you have a record of the the attempts that succeeded.

If you think about it, these entities really do serve two separate business purposes. So it makes sense to have two entities.

Final note: Of course, you could just delete the `RecordCreation` entity once the `Record` entity is complete. But then you don't have the logging, so troubleshooting the app is harder. I prefer to mark it with the date.

Answer (score 0):

When the user starts to create a new item, add a placeholder one in the database.
Populate one of the fields with a GUID or something else similarly distinct.
Look up the item with the matching GUID and get it's code.
That is your reserved code.

When the user is ready to save just update the existing placeholder record.
Remember to delete the placeholder if the user cancels the creation.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a "seed table" for this.  When you "reserve" a new code - increment the seed value by 1 and return the result.   Whether you want to add entities to do that or just use SQL is up to you.  I personally would just use SQL to reduce the risk of two requests getting the same code.  If you do it all in SQL you can virtually elimitate the by doing the select and update in one statement:

```
DECLARE @newID int 

UPDATE SeedTable 
SET NextID = NextID + 1,
    @newID = NextID

SELECT @newID, * FROM SeedTable
```

Since the select and update happen in one statement you should be safe from concurrent requests.

One drawback is that codes are not guaranteed to be consecutive.  If you reserve one number but don't use it you will have a gap in the numbers.  It shouldn't be an issue, but some people get anal about having consecutive